# How do I get the login SDDM to use large fonts on my hidpi display?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, hdpi, sddm

On Kubuntu 22.04, I've configured my desktop session to use a suitably large font with System Settings > Display and Monitor > Display Configuration > Global scale. But the SDDM remains unpleasantly small.

I tried a variety of configuration changes based on other answers, creating and modifying various files, primarily in `/etc/sddm.conf.d` , but either did nothing or, in some cases, caused SDDM to display a *wildly* different screen, perhaps because it was unable to parse my new settings.

This was particularly frustrating when I experimented with changing System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Login Screen (SDDM) > Behavior...; the automatically created `/etc/sddm_conf.d/kde-something-or-another` file caused SDDM to display something wildly unexpected.

How can I get SDDM to respect my "Global scale"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in System Settings > Startup and Shutdown > Login Screen (SDDM) > Apply Plasma Settings.... You'll need root access (you'll probably just be prompted for your password when you try to apply them). After that a quick log out and SDDM gave me nice, large, readable fonts.